# appRole defined in AzureAD application not being included for guest user of type "External Azure Active Directory"

Tags: azure-active-directory, roles, azure-ad-b2b

Have AzureAD application for authentication with appRoles defined in the manifest.  The roles are assigned to users and they are included in tokens of authenticated users as claims.  This is the case with members of the current tenant as well as newly added guest users of type "Microsoft Account" for the source of authority.  (The signInAudience of the application is set as AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount in the manifest.)

But for an existing guest user of type "External Azure Active Directory" for the source of authority, the appRole is not coming through the token claims.  Is it worth trying to delete the guest user account and try readding it?  Wouldn't this particular feature/behavior of appRoles be the same whether the source of authority for the guest account is "Microsoft Account" or "External Azure Active Directory"?

Or wondering might there be some additional/complementary setting that needs to be set or adjusted for the "External Azure Active Directory"?

PS: the authorization endpoint used currently is https://login.microsoftonline.com/common, and it authenticates just it's not getting the appRole, and it works with the appRole for the "Microsoft Account" type of guest account.  Should that be changed however..?

Comment: How are you signing in guest MSA users on /common?  They will default to their home tenant (the MSA tenant), so any assigned roles won't show up. Similarly, if you sign the guest user in on /common, you'll get their roles in their home tenant, not the resource tenant... Which it sounds like aren't set.

Answer (score 4):

Yup that was it.  Based on suspicion tried changing the authority to tenant based https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com and it worked... yes because guest user of type "External Azure Active Directory" would of course authentication against their tenant if using https://login.microsoftonline.com/common, and get their roles.  So by forcing to authenticate against specific tenant where they are registered as guest users (where the roles are defined), the roles are added to the claims.  Of course guest users of type "Microsoft Account" don't have their own tenants so were being authenticated against the tenant anyway... ha ha.  Just found out this morning worked.  First time using AAD, but kind of makes sense when think about it...  Thnks!